# Python Linked List Class Definitions

Tags: python, linked-list

I ran into something interesting whilst learning about Data Structures and Algorithms in Python - particularly the implementation of Linked Lists. While defining the Class Definitions for the Linked List’s Node and the Linked List itself, I noticed some examples define the Node Class with both the “Value” and the “Next” Properties as Arguments in the Initialization Method, and other examples define said Node Class with only the “Value” Property as an Argument in the Initialization Method - keeping the “Next” Property as a Locally Defined Variable from the perspective of the Node Class itself.

I am hypothesizing that the latter is more accurate and secure since it should be the role and responsibility of the Linked List Class to modify the Node’s “Next” property, making the code more secure and removing the possibility of accidental modification.

Could someone confirm this for me and please tell me if my assumptions are accurate? If they are not, could someone break this down for me a little more and correct my hypothesis?

I tried looking up examples of how to properly define Classes for Linked Lists and Nodes.

The following are excerpts of the examples I was referring to…

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, value, next_node=None, prev_node=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next_node
    self.prev = prev_node

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.value)
class LinkedList:
def __init__(self, values=None):
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None
    if values is not None:
        self.add_multiple_nodes(values)
def __str__(self):
    return ' -> '.join([str(node) for node in self])
def __len__(self):
    count = 0
    node = self.head
    while node:
        count += 1
        node = node.next
    return count
def __iter__(self):
    current = self.head
    while current:
        yield current
        current = current.next
@property
def values(self):
    return [node.value for node in self]
def add_node(self, value):
    if self.head is None:
        self.tail = self.head = Node(value)
    else:
        self.tail.next = Node(value)
        self.tail = self.tail.next
    return self.tail
def add_multiple_nodes(self, values):
    for value in values:
        self.add_node(value)
def add_node_as_head(self, value):
    if self.head is None:
        self.tail = self.head = Node(value)
    else:
        self.head = Node(value, self.head)
    return self.head
```

Compared to…

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None

def __repr__(self):
    return self.data

class LinkedList:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

def __repr__(self):
    node = self.head
    nodes = []
    while node is not None:
        nodes.append(node.data)
        node = node.next
    nodes.append("None")
    return " -> ".join(nodes)
```

Comment: If you state that it's the Linked List Class to modify the Node’s “Next” property, then that Next property cannot be private to the Node class.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided the code for the two (or more?) patterns you are bringing on the table.

Comment: Whether you can set the `next` property immediately on instantiation or you must wait until after the node is created to set it doesn't matter too much, since a linked list must have some way to *change* the `next` attribute of any given node anyway.

Comment: What do you see when you also consider the code that implements list manipulation? Do you then still have a question? If yes, then please provide the LinkedList class implementation of list manipulation (insert, remove, ...). NB: you have provided two pieces of code which do not do the same thing (one is a doubly linked node, the other a singly linked node, one has `__str__`)

Comment: The second snippet has a `LinkedList` class that does not offer any methods to manipulate the list. How is the user of the second snippet supposed to add/remove nodes? For a fair comparison, both should expose the **same** methods. NB: the code will not parse because the indentation is off.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking whether it is more "accurate and secure" to have a `Node` constructor that does *not* take a `next` argument, and give the following in defence:

> it should be the role and responsibility of the Linked List Class to modify the Node’s “Next” property

This is a true statement, but whether or not the `Node` constructor has this extra parameter does not really have an impact on that. The `LinkedList` class will need a way to link nodes together, which means that the `Node` class has to expose a way to do that, either via a method, or by directly setting its `next` attribute, or ... via the constructor. For instance, if the `LinkedList` has a method to insert a value at a given index, then two Node-referencing attributes will need to be set: the new node's `next` attribute and the `next` attribute of the new node's predecessor (or the head reference of the linked list).

> making the code more secure and removing the possibility of accidental modification.

The `LinkedList` class should of course be designed so that there is no room for accidents. The risk is more at the side of the code that will *use* the `LinkedList` class.

The two implementations you have provided can hardly be compared, as the second one doesn't even offer methods to manipulate the linked list -- it doesn't have code that creates/adds nodes to its list. Apparently the user of these classes is supposed to create the `Node` instances themselves, which really is a bad idea. The first one implements a doubly linked list, and also maintains a reference to the tail node. As it provides methods for managing the linked list, it is superior to the second implementation. On the negative side, the first implementation has methods that return `Node` instances to the caller, who could then (accidentally?) set the `next` attribute of this node potentially breaking the linked list.

To better protect the linked list from "accidents", you could decide to not expose any `Node` reference to the code that instantiates a `LinkedList`. This you don't achieve by removing the `next` parameter fro the `Node` constructor, but by forbidding (or at least discouraging) the *user* of your `LinkedList` class to tamper with the nodes that are in the list. You can achieve that by taking the following measures:

- Make clear that the head reference (and tail reference, if there is one) is an internal implementation detail. In Python you do this by naming it with an underscore (`_head`).
- Don't have methods in the `LinkedList` class that take a `Node` reference as argument, nor that return or yield a `Node` reference.

This way the user of `LinkedList` will never access the nodes directly, but will only communicate *values* with the `LinkedList` class.

Having the `next` parameter in the `Node` constructor can actually help to make the `LinkedList` implementation more concise.

Here is a possible implementation of such "protective" `LinkedList` class:

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value, next=None):
            self.value = value
            self.next = next
    
        def get(self, index):
            if index >= 0:
                for _ in range(index):
                    self = self.next
                    if not self:
                        break
                return self
    
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self._head = None
        for value in reversed(values):
            self.push(value)

    def isempty(self):
        return not self._head
    
    def push(self, value):
        self._head = self.Node(value, self._head)

    def pop(self):
        if not self.isempty():
            value = self._head.value
            self._head = self._head.next
            return value

    def insert(self, index, value):
        if index == 0:
            return self.push(value)
        prev = self._head.get(index - 1)
        if prev:
            prev.next = self.Node(value, prev.next)
        
    def delete(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return self.pop()
        prev = self._head.get(index - 1)
        if prev and prev.next:
            value = prev.next.value
            prev.next = prev.next.next
            return value
        
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self._head
        while node:
            yield node.value  # don't expose nodes; only values
            node = node.next


lst = LinkedList(10, 20, 30, 40)
print(lst.pop())       # 10
print(*lst)            # 20 30 40
lst.insert(1, 10)
print(*lst)            # 20 10 30 40
lst.insert(4, 50)
print(*lst)            # 20 10 30 40 50
lst.delete(4)
print(*lst)            # 20 10 30 40
lst.delete(0)
print(*lst)            # 10 30 40
```